# Pure CSS Line-Height reduction as Font-Size Increases with example but only works in one direction

Tags: css, css-calc, clamp, line-height

I found a dynamic way in pure css to reduce the `line-height` as the font size increases by using a series of nested `clamps`.

Essentially we ascertain the font size using the `em` unit and then add the number of additional pixels we want to add to the `line-height` until the range is exceeded.

```
.dynamic-line-height {
  line-height: clamp(
    clamp(
      clamp(
        clamp(
          clamp(
            clamp(
              clamp(25px, 1em + 8px, 28px),
              1em + 7px, 32px
            ),
            1em + 6px, 34px
          ),
          1em + 5px, 40px
        ),
        1em + 4px, 76px
      ),
      1em + 3px, 92px
    ),
    1em + 2px, 9999px
  );
}
```

You get the idea.

Now while this works with decreasing the `line-height` as the `font-size` increases I want to also initially **increase** the `line height` **before decreasing** it like this, however there is a *troublemaker.

The issue is that the largest conceivable `<preferred size>` is taking precedence over the values that precede it. So in the example below anything with a `line-height` of less than `25px` receives the formula of `1em + 8px` instead of that assigned to it.

CSS

```
p {
  line-height: clamp(
    clamp(
      clamp(
        clamp(
          clamp(
            clamp(
              clamp(
                clamp(
                  clamp(
                    clamp(1px, 1em + 4px, 12px), 
                    1em + 6px, 18px
                  ),
                  1em + 7px, 25px
                ),
                1em + 8px, 28px
              ),
              1em + 7px, 32px
            ),
            1em + 6px, 34px
          ),
          1em + 5px, 40px
        ),
        1em + 4px, 76px
      ),
      1em + 3px, 92px
    ),
    1em + 2px, 9999px
  );
}
```

HTML

```
<p style="font-size: 12px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>

<p style="font-size: 17px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>

<p style="font-size: 20px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>

<p style="font-size: 24px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>


<p style="font-size: 28px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>


<p style="font-size: 40px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>


<p style="font-size: 60px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>

<p style="font-size: 80px;">
  Hello there<br>hello there
</p>
```

Testing area
https://jsfiddle.net/x08cpjug/3/

So looking at the first paragraph with font-size set to 12 px you can see that it is providing a line-height of 1em + 8px (ie. 20px) when it should in fact be using 1em + 4px (ie. 16px).

[image]

A very rough graph showing the additional number of px above 1em to be added to line-height (vertical axis) against the font-size (horizontal axis).

Comment: why not just use ems for the line height - then if the font size changes, the line-height will also automatically change as em is based on the font size

Comment: if you use the formula `X - n*1em` where X is a length (px for example) and n is a number, you will have a linear function for your line-height that decrease when the font-size increase

Comment: tbh I tried to read it, but as you didn't provide a [mcve] or explain what was changing the font-size, I only skimmed it.  ps no need to be so rude with your thousand question marks, my comment was only a suggestion

Comment: @Pete Thanks Pete. Your comment is completely invalid to the question. I'm not being rude I merely pointing out that there is no way you could have read it which is also a recommendation before commenting. And seriously, this took less than 50 seconds to put together. https://jsfiddle.net/x08cpjug/3/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Could you elaborate a little more. That sounds ideal but how to set the n value and have it follow what ideally is a curve line graph not a straight multiplication? Thanks very much,

Comment: What is the shape of the graph you would like it to follow?

Comment: 1em + 4px until font size reaches 12 px, then steadily increase to 1em + 8px arriving there at a font size of 18px. Then steadily decrease once font size is over 20px until font size is 36px where it is 1em + 4px again. The very slowly decrease from there until font size is 80px where line height should be 1em + 2px. Given how specific this is, this is why I went for the clamp function.

Comment: So line height at 80px will be 82px and line haight at 79px will be 82px? Am struggling to understand. Is there any background reason for this tiny (and not-seemingly logical) difference?

Comment: Exactly but at 78px it will be 81px, 77px 80px etc.. I've drawn a graph that may give you a better idea and added it to the question.

Comment: @AHaworth Whilst the graph drawing is crude you can basely see that the purpose is to create a bell-curve peaking at a font size of 17px.

Comment: A runnable snippet would be good, along with info on what debugging you have tried.

Comment: The fiddle is active. jsfiddle.net/x08cpjug/3 and in terms of debugging its entirely written in the question. It's not a bug. Either clamp can't be used beyond the above mathematically or there is a way of creating a formula that will support it beyond my comprehension. I recognise that no one is quite realising the significance of this but in many circumstances line-height is critical to achieving design goals. My clamp formula solves the need to write a custom css class for every intended font-size. I wrongly assumed it would be of major interest instead of ridicule (not from you per say)

Comment: You may have misunderstood why SO asks for runnable code actually in the question. External sites disappear thus rendering the question useless for future readers.

Comment: I see. I've been working in Dart for years. Last time I worked with web languages "Solving a fiddle" appeared to be the standard approach. I'll make some edits.

Answer (score 0):

An answer of sorts.

Clamp cannot overcome the limitation stated in the question but the problem can be reduced. In the question the minimum line-height is 1em + 8px until the line-height reaches 28px, thus a font-size of 12px will provide a line-height of 20px instead of the intended 16px.

While this cannot be completely solved with clamp we can use an em value that is closer to achieving what was desired. Instead of 1em + 8px being the effective minimum preferred size value we can say 1.48em is the minimum preferred size value.

This would make a font-size of 12px have a line-height of 17.76px. Not quite 16px but certainly smaller than 20px.

Therefore using the em value without adding pixels is the closest approximation to achieving the a solution with clamp.

```
--line-height--dynamic: clamp(
    clamp(
      clamp(
        clamp(
          clamp(
            clamp(
              clamp(
                clamp(
                  clamp(
                    clamp(clamp(1em, 1.48em, 25px), 1.4em, 28px),
                    1.28em,
                    32px
                  ),
                  1.16em,
                  36px
                ),
                1.12em,
                40px
              ),
              1.1em,
              44px
            ),
            1.08em,
            54px
          ),
          1.06em,
          68px
        ),
        1.04em,
        80px
      ),
      1.02em,
      96px
    ),
    1em,
    128px
  );
}
```

Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/zc608kg5/1/

*This question really suffered from an overabundance of support and experimentation. I don't know everyone managed to contain their enthusiasm.*